# Apache Spark java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver for my Azure SQL Server

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

I am suddenly getting the error message **java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver**  when I try to connect to my Azure SQL Server from my Databricks notebook. I have been successfully connecting without any issues for as long as I can remember. Therefore, I'm guessing that there is a worldwide platform issue with Apache Spark/Databricks, but not sure.

```py
jdbcUrl = f"jdbc:sqlserver://{DBServer}.database.windows.net:1433;database={DBDatabase};user={DBUser};password={DBPword};encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;"  
df = spark.read.csv("/mnt/lake/RAW/cashsales_1.csv")  
df.write.mode("overwrite") \
     .format("jdbc") \
     .option("url", jdbcUrl) \
     .option("dbtable", 'UpdatedProducts')\
     .save()
```

If that is not the case, can someone let me know how to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: show the code. SQL Server driver should be a part of DBR

Comment: Morning @AlexOtt, it was a bit silly of me to not include the code. Here you go: ```jdbcUrl = f"jdbc:sqlserver://{DBServer}.database.windows.net:1433;database={DBDatabase};user={DBUser};password={DBPword};encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;"

df = spark.read.csv("/mnt/lake/RAW/cashsales_1.csv")

df.write.mode("overwrite") \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", jdbcUrl) \
    .option("dbtable", 'UpdatedProducts')\
    .save()```

Comment: Also, can you let me know if there is a way to paste my code in SE in a more legible way?

Comment: just press "Edit" button on the post itself

Comment: is it community edition or azure databricks? also - what version of DBR?

Comment: Its a Community Edition, but I've never had this problem before

Comment: I really desperately need this to work, as I'm still training and its cost too much to develop and train in Azure

Comment: Oh, I just noticed you asked for the DBR. Its 8.3 (includes Apache Spark 3.1.1, Scala 2.12)

Comment: have you checked this first step: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/sql-databases#step-1-check-that-the-jdbc-driver-is-available

Comment: Hi @AlexOtt, while waiting for your response, I changed the DBR to 7.3 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.0.1, Scala 2.12) and I was able to connect to the SQL Server. I will try implementing the solution you provided in the link

Comment: it's interesting... I think that it should be escalated via support

Comment: Hi @AlexOtt, is escalating the issue to support something that you can do (seeing as you're with Databricks? Or would I need to somehow get in touch with Databricks?

Comment: if you on Azure, you can open Azure ticket.

Comment: Hi @AlexOtt, once again, thanks for your help. I will open an Azure ticket